# Replacing my "Add to Cart" link with "Out of Stock"

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp, shopping-cart, cart

I'm trying to, for the sake of a class project, create a mock-up store. My tools are XAMPP 3.2.2 and phpMyAdmin. An actual, functioning "Add to cart" button will come later(Right now I'm just using a link as a placeholder), but for the time being, I'm trying to figure out how to replace the button/link with a message reading "Out of Stock" when the Stock is 0.

Here's the code I'm using to display the product page; it's almost certainly messy, and there's probably a dozen better ways to do it, but for now, it gets the job done:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM webstore.Products order by category";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
 // output data of each row
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

      echo '<table border="2" width="100%">';
      echo '<tr>';
                   echo '  <td width="20%">' . $row["Name"] . '</td>';
                  echo '  <td width="20%">' . $row["Descr"] . '</td>';
                   echo '  <td width="20%">' . $row["Price"] . '</td>';
                   echo '  <td width="20%">' . '<img src =' . $row["IconURL"] . '>' . '</td>';
                   echo '  <td width="20%">' . '<a href ="http://localhost:81/shopping_cart.php">Add to cart</a>' . '</td>';
                   echo '  </tr> ';  
                    echo '</table>';
 }
} else {
 echo "0 results";
}
```

The output looks like this:
[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0dr3.png)

I'm not looking for "better practices;" right now, I just need a way to replace the shopping cart link with "Out of Stock" when the product stock is 0.

Comment: is stock quantity in webstore.Products ?

Comment: Where is the `stock` row? You can easily add conditional statement as `if ( stock > 0 ) { //echo url } else { // echo stock 0 }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a check to the while loop some what like:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

  echo '<table border="2" width="100%">';
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '  <td width="20%">' . $row["Name"] . '</td>';
  echo '  <td width="20%">' . $row["Descr"] . '</td>';
  echo '  <td width="20%">' . $row["Price"] . '</td>';
  echo '  <td width="20%">' . '<img src =' . $row["IconURL"] . '>' . '</td>';
if($row['stock'] >0){  
echo '  <td width="20%">' . '<a href ="http://localhost:81/shopping_cart.php">Add to cart</a>' . '</td>';
}else{
echo '<td width="20%">Out of Stock</td>';
}  

echo '  </tr> ';  

  echo '</table>';
 }
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Had to swap the if and else around for it to work (No clue why), but work it did. Thank you.